# Size of Token IDs used in Desire2Learn's REST API authentication?

Tags: authentication, desire2learn

The documentation for the REST API authentication scheme describes the Token Keys used for auth as 22 characters in length. How long are the Token IDs, though -- are they also 22 characters?

Answer (score 0):

The IDs coming back from the learning suite are also 22 character strings.